# Is it possible to access Twitter Ads API using OAuth2?

Tags: twitter

I need to get all Twitter ad accounts using OAuth2.
When I make request to `https://ads-api.twitter.com/11/accounts1` with valid OAuth2 bearer token supplied I'm getting this error:

```
{
   "title": "Forbidden",
   "type": "about:blank",
   "status": 403,
   "detail": "You are not permitted to use OAuth2 on this endpoint"
}
```

Scopes for the token: `tweet.read, users.read, follows.read, follows.write, offline.access`

Is it possible to use Twitter Ads API using OAuth2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not right now - the Ads API is looking into moving to OAuth 2:

> We are recruiting developers for a private beta for OAuth 2.0.

You can [apply for the beta](https://twittercommunity.com/t/ads-api-oauth-2-0-beta/172589), but this is not generally available (as of June 2022)